# De esas benditas e impredecibles conjugaciones

Tags: verbos, historia, tiempos-verbales, conjugación

En el Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas se manejan 46 modelos de conjugación irregulares y en particular, el verbo que me llama la atención por sus 'derivados' es [decir](https://www.rae.es/dpd/ayuda/modelos-de-conjugacion-verbal#n28), como por ejemplo *[predecir](https://dle.rae.es/predecir?m=form)* o *[bendecir](https://dle.rae.es/bendecir?m=form)*. Sin embargo, las conjugaciones de estos verbos difieren levemente del original, en tiempos como el futuro o el imperativo en ambos casos y en el pospretérito de predecir. Como en latín todos estos verbos finalizan en *dicĕre*, el cambio parece darse en español (sin haber hecho la tarea de revisar alguna lengua romance que confirme la teoría). ¿Cuál de las conjugaciones en los tiempos nombrados era la *original* (imperativos supuestos de *tú predí* y *tú bendí* o el *tú dice* e igual para futuros y pospretéritos) ? ¿Hacia que siglos se habría visto reflejado el cambio en los verbos?

Comment: En italiano, los futuros son iguales en los tres verbos, pero en el imperativo de *tu* también hay un cambio: *di* vs *benedici* / *predici*. Véase [aquí](https://www.wordreference.com/conj/ItVerbs.aspx?v=predire), donde las excepciones al modelo *dire* están convenientemente marcadas en rojo, y donde a la izquierda hay links a todos los verbos derivados de *dire*.

Comment: La composición de _bendecir_ y _maldecir_ ocurrió en el latín. Ambas palabras llegaron al español ya formadas. Además, fueron de uso frecuente en el latín de misa. Eso explicaría en parte que no siguieran siempre el mismo camino de _decir_.